# How to upgrade xcode4.5.1 to 4.6?

Tags: xcode, ios6.1

Is there anyway to upgrade existing xcode4.5.1 to xcode4.6 without downloading 1.65GB of complete file download.
I want to work on  iOS6.1 development, so i would like to upgrade by xcode to support new iOS version.
Instead of downloading this huge file, is there any way to get only updates?

Comment: That huge file is Xcode4.6. You want just the xcode binary without the updated SDKs?

Answer (score 1):

It was my understanding that you have to download and install the .dmg file for xcode 4.6.  There is no "upgrade to latest version".  Once you download 4.6 you will still have 4.5 as well (and then you can delete if if you do not want it).

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of new features inside the xcode 4.6 so without downloading 1.65 file you cannot upgrade to 4.5 to 4.6

please refer the release note
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/